# Hail to Pnrfne!

Tags: word, enigmatic-puzzle

1. sgd vnqkc'r rszmczqc tmhs ne dkdbsqhbzk qdrhrszmbd, ok. (4)
2. y rfcmpw, yzzp.(3)

---

3. x Yfkf xka Vloryx qfqib clo zboqxfk olvxi oribop (3)
4. iqoeywh ejopnqiajp sepd sepd w znqihega xkzu, w bnappaz jayg, wjz opnejco (5)

---

5. mvoczm izr vxmjith ajm v xjdi cvqdib v hdiodib zmmjm (4)
6. bucl mbujyx fcey mguff vlyux (3)

---

7. ftdx lahnml hy tiikhote (5)
8. sf zwjtsyw, mkmsddq yjskk, egowv sfv umjwv xgj xgvvwj (3)

---

9. jkivrd fw nrkvi fw ljlrccp tfejzuvirscv mfcldv (5)
10. je fhelytu myjx qd utwu (3)

---

11. ixcn epgih iwpi pgt sxuutgtci (ph xc rdadg) ugdb iwt bpxc epgi (5)
12. hvs hmds ct oqcighwq uiwhof hvoh vog o ashoz fsgcbohcf piwzh wbhc hvs pcrm (5)

---

The answer is a 3-letter word.

Update: 
I left this comment on CodeWarrior0's recent answer:

> Nice summary table. You're the first to list the 6 items. Almost there. The "Hail to Caesar" part is over. One final aha remains. Nice ideas, PDT, but It is very simple, so rule out anything complex to save time. Everything you need is in the post. No need to go digging in other places.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The answer is

> PIG

Because...

> Encrypting each line using a Caesar cipher whose shift is the same as its clue number produces a crossword clue. The answer to each clue may be encrypted using the same cipher to produce a new word. The answers, encrypted words, and clues are:
>
> ```
> 1.  OHMS   PINT   the world's standard unit of electrical resistance, pl. (4)
> 2.  HYP    JAR    a theory, abbr.(3)
> 3.  OBA    RED    a Bini and Yoruba title for certain royal rulers (3)
> 4.  BANJO  FERNS  musical instrument with with a drumlike body, a fretted neck, and strings (5)
> 5.  FIDO   KNIT   rather new acronym for a coin having a minting error (4)
> 6.  BUN    HAT    hair shaped like small bread (3)
> 7.  CHEER  JOLLY  make shouts of approval (5)
> 8.  HAY    PIG    an herbage, usually grass, mowed and cured for fodder (3)
> 9.  RIVER  ARENA  stream of water of usually considerable volume (5)
> 10. HEM    ROW    to provide with an edge (3)
> 11. SPOTS  DAZED  tiny parts that are different (as in color) from the main part (5)
> 12. DOBRO  PANDA  the type of acoustic guitar that has a metal resonator built into the body (5)
> ```

> The clues are given in groups of two. The encrypted words when taken in pairs seem to be related somehow, but that's a false lead.
>
> ```
> PINT   JAR
> RED    FERNS
> KNIT   HAT
> JOLLY  PIG
> ARENA  ROW
> DAZED  PANDA
> ```

> Return to the deciphered clues, and use each clue's enumeration to find that letter of the clue.
>
> ```
>  the worl... (4) gives W
>  a theor...  (3) gives H
>  a Bini and..(3) gives I
>     (and so on)
> ```

> These letters spell out `WHICH IS HAPPY`, and a `JOLLY PIG` is found in the paired answers to the clues, so the three-letter word you're looking for is `PIG`.

Comment: +1 Nice summary table. You're the first to list the 6 items. Almost there. The "Hail to Caesar" part is over. One final aha remains. Nice ideas, PDT, but It is very simple, so rule out anything complex to save time. Everything you need is in the post. No need to go digging in other places.

Comment: Good puzzle. I have to credit a mysterious stranger for finding the last part for me. I had all of the answers except for #5 shortly after the puzzle was posted, since I had recognized #4 and #9 from my own experiments with this kind of thing, so I have to credit one of the other answerers for #5 too.

Comment: yep. you nailed it.

Answer (score 3):

## Partial Answer

We first

> Apply rot1 to the first clue, rot2 to the second, etc.

Solving yields:

> Ohms, HYP, Oba, Banjo, Fido, Bun, Sweet/Bravo/**Cheer**, Hay, River, XXX,  XXXXX, Dobro

We can solve the three possible alternative clues by reverse engineering, since

> Applying rot1 ~ rot12 again to each clue gives

> pint, jar, red, ferns, knit, hat, jolly, pig, arena, XXX, XXXXX, panda

I suspect

> Putting pairs of word and deducing another word from each pair

but

> I don't have enough solved clues for that.

Also

> `Pnrfne` menas `Caesar`.

Comment: I can't see deleted answers :(

Comment: +1 lookin good so far. Don't overthink it.

Comment: @Jlee is #10 cut/med?

Comment: @JLee absolutely no idea for #11 tho

Comment: @SnySmartie not cut med. But you got the one that the 1st answerers didn't.